Specialization of points in a scheme
Let $X$ be an arbitrary scheme and $x \in X$ and $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$ a specialization of $x$. I am wondering if there exists an affine open $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ containing both $x$ and $y$. I am working through a problem where it would be convenient to work locally on an affine scheme where the points $x$ and $y$ correspond to prime ideals.

Hint: must an open neighborhood of $y$ contain $x$? Why or why not?

Thanks, I am able to prove the claim now. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $y$ not containing $x$. Then $x \in X \backslash U$, and since $ X \backslash U$ is closed and the closure of $x$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $x$, we have that $y \in \overline{{x}} \subset X \backslash U$, but $y \in U$ as well, which is a contradiction.

Great! Please post this as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Thanks to @KReiser's helpful comment, I am able to prove the claim now. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $y$ not containing $x$. Then $x \in X \backslash U$, and since $X \backslash U$ is closed and the closure of $x$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $x$, we have that $y \in \overline{\{x\}} \subset X \backslash U$, but $y \in U$ as well, which is a contradiction.
